# How can I fix Print Composer errors due to huge file size?

Tags: qgis, printing

I have put together a map using the British OS Strategi data set which is pretty densely detailed. It is surveyed at 1:250,000 and so contains roads down to track level, rivers, villages, railway lines - you name it. There's a lot of data.

When I try and export an image version of the map (at about 1m x 1m), I always get an 'Exception: bad allocation' error. This happens when I try to export as a raster image or PDF. I have tried printing to a PDF generator (CutePDF) but the same thing happens. The print spooler shows the file size at 1.6Gb.

I am running QGIS on a dual core 2ghz Windows 8 system with 4Gb of RAM. Is it just a case of the file being too big? Is there anything I can do? Or is there an alternative, free GIS package that would do a similar job?

Comment: I guess you've already tried reducing the resolution set for the exported image? Perhaps it might be worth trying with a resolution of 150 dpi (or even 96 dpi).

Comment: I need the image to be printable with reasonable quality for a wall map, so not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in printing large formats on Windows systems:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/qgis-and-Large-Format-Print-td5016300.html

If the hints given there won't help you, you can install a 64bit linux system, or have to wait until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Is the issue with windows or 32 bits? Obviously Windows 8 is 64 bit, but is Windows QGIS?

Comment: No, QGis binaries for Windows are still 32-bit, but run on 64-bit Operating systems.

Comment: I've installed a 64-bit version of Ubuntu and get the same problem - it appears to be just too much data. Disappointing.

Comment: Have you checked "export as raster"? This breaks exporting in large formats for me. So better leave it unchecked.

Comment: No, unchecked. I've also tried printing to a PDF and exporting as a raster image, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the two methods suggested above and neither helped me. After 1 hour of switching off and on layers, I finally found that going to:

Properties->Labels (depreciated) -> Buffer labels

and switching off buffering solved the problem.

Even a few polygons with just a few text labels generates file sizes of 10's MB which crash my network printer! I think this should be filed as a bug, though it does say "deprecated" so maybe this will be fixed in future versions. I am using :

QGIS version    2.2.0-Valmiera  QGIS code revision  c3a2817

On Windows 7, 64 bit. Downloaded 02.06.2014

Comment: Just move from deprecated labeling to new labeling. The deprecated version is only there for backwards compatibility with old QGIS projects.