# Large File Sizes and Print Composer not printing

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I have been working on a heavily detailed map using qgis for the last two years. I am runnig QGIS Essen 2.14.1 on a windows 7 home premium 64 bit with 4gb ram. The file size of the map is around 150mb. i was nearing the the end of the project until this monolithic problem has arisen and i am not able to print the map using the composer. I get a 1cm band at the top of the page which looks great, nothing on the rest of the page and printer loads another sheet and sits there for about 10 minutes or so and then gifts me a blank page.  I initially thought it was a question of upgrading RAM but it seems, from what i have so far found, that there is a bug within qgis when trying to print high res. or  high dpi maps.

Printing at a low DPI is not an option.

The issuses i am having a very similar to a previous question:- [How can I fix Print Composer errors due to huge file size?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41297/how-can-i-fix-print-composer-errors-due-to-huge-file-size)

However the 'workaround' suggested there  doesnt seem to be applicable with Essen. Is there a way through or around this this using just QGIS...